# Iterate over list using lambda to get nested lists

Tags: python

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4]]

pca( map(lambda v: v, a))
```

I have a need to pass individual nested lists one by one to this function. But I get only the entire list back. Not the embedded lists. What obvious technique am I missing here ?

Update ( I am able to solve this problem based on comments ):

This code uses Spark's Python library and its own data structures and I am porting it using Python's libraries. I mistakenly tried to use it without understanding the syntax of Python's *map* which can take *pca* as the first parameter and a nested list as the second. It tripped me because I am not used to Python.

The flow starts from this line which was the problem. I modified the rest of the code too.

```
componentsScaled, scaledScores, eigenvaluesScaled = pca( scaledData.map(lambda (k, v): v),3)



def estimateCovariance( data ):
mean = getmean( data )
dataZeroMean = data.map(lambda x : x - mean )
cov = dataZeroMean.map(lambda x : np.outer(x,x)).mean()
return cov

"""Computes the top `k` principal components, corresponding scores, and all eigenvalues.

"""
def pca(data, k=2):
eigVals, eigVecs = eigh(estimateCovariance(data))
inds = np.argsort(eigVals)[::-1]
topComponent = eigVecs[:,inds[:k]]
correlatedDataScores = data.map(lambda x : np.dot(x,topComponent))
return topComponent,correlatedDataScores,eigVals[inds]
```

Comment: I'm confused. What exactly are you trying to do? Your `lambda` doesn't really do anything, it returns its arguments. Do you want `map(pca, a)`? What arguments does the `pca` function expect?

Comment: what does the pca function do? Just calling `map(function, lists)` will pass each list to the function so why would that not work?

Comment: What is `scaledData`?

Comment: I am showing Spark's Python library data structures. But `map(function, lists)` does send the nested lists. I may have overused lambdas.

Comment: @Blckknght Question was simpler than I thought but yours was the first answer.

Comment: Despite several attempts to edit the question and clearly choosing the answer SO closes it !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do something like this,

```
a = [[1,2], [3,4]]
what_you_want = [pca([1,2]), pca([3,4])]
```

you should pass `pca` to `map` instead of `lambda`. `map` alrady does the thing you want `lambda` to do - it applies the function passed to it (`pca`) to each element of the list `a`.

```
what_you_want = map(pca, a)
```